# Renew Apple developer certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, app-store

I am about a week away of expiration of the Apple developer certificate. Accidentally I lost the CSR file which I used when I created the last certificate which I am currently using.

What issues might I face if I go with another CSR for new certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

1. Without CSR, you will be able to work with existing certificate but once it expires, you must create new one and you can use/create new CSR if previous one is lost.
2. Updating your certificate will not impact on your distributed build on public environment (Apple App Store). But of-course it won't allow you to distribute your new build with invalid/expired certificate.

Here is an instruction from Apple Developer Documentation for [Code Signing Identity](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html), that says,

> If you lose control of your Apple-issued signing identity, such as
>   your Developer ID or Mac App Distribution identity, report this to
>   Apple immediately. Apple will invalidate the old identity and help you
>   to replace it. While this seems like a bit of work, it is critical,
>   because anyone possessing your identity can distribute potentially
>   malicious or destructive code that looks like it came from you.

This may also help you.

**[No Code Signing Identities Found](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW7)**

Xcode detects when you’re missing a signing identity. Typically, this happens when you move from one Mac to another. Follow the steps in Creating the Team Provisioning Profile to create your signing identity and add it to the team provisioning profile. You’ll have the option of importing your signing identity from another Mac or resetting it. If you use a custom development provisioning profile that you manage yourself, it becomes invalid after revoking the development certificate. Read Editing Provisioning Profiles in Your Developer Account to regenerate it.

To avoid this problem, export your certificates as a developer profile file on the other Mac, and then import them on your new Mac, as described in Exporting and Importing Certificates and Profiles.

Comment: I know these things and I do these. My question is different, I am questioning as I don't have the old CSR with me now and I m applying for certificate with new CSR from same device. Will it work or not?

Comment: I am primarily asking for certificate signing request (CSR).

Comment: I believe then I will create a new certificate using a new CSR and then update all provisioning profile with them and I think then I can push update to new apps Am I right?

Comment: Yes, of-course. Also note, you can change as many as CSR & Certificates during development mode. Just make sure valid certificate & provisioning profile is assigned to your project target

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation `.CSR` is used in combination with your App ID, provisioning profile and entitlements. So, if one have both (App ID and provisioning profile) it will harmful to you.

[.CSR explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)